# python not working correctly when called from nodejs app with child-process

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

Im trying to run a python script that used deep learning model to classify an image wether it is NSFW or not, i use this script from here https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw and a custom model. The python script runs ok when called directly with python, but when called from nodejs app via child-process, the script stops at this line

```
# Pre-load caffe model.
nsfw_net = caffe.Net(model_def, pretrained_model, caffe.TEST)
```

Everything else in python works fine. And the script run directly works fine too. Why it is not working when called from child-process?

When i run it from a node app like this

```
    const cp = require("child_process")
    const spawn = cp.spawn;
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python',['/home/ubuntu/classify.py']);

    pythonProcess.stdin.write(req.body.image, function(err){
        pythonProcess.stdin.end();
    });

    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log("message from python:" + data)
        });

    pythonProcess.stdout.on("end", (data) => {
        console.log("end received data: " + data);
        res.status(200);
        res.end(); 
    });
```

Comment: Any specific error or does it just hang on that line?

Comment: It just hangs on that line, i have log lines before and after, the before line i see in output, the after line is not see, and no errors. Could this be because the python process outputs lots of logs when loading the model and then struggles flushing all the data to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by adding `pythonProcess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);` to my nodejs app and then i was able to see python errors and fixed them. There were mistakes in the python script.